# Java native code string ending

Tags: java-native-interface

Does the string returned from the [`GetStringUTFChars()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#wp17265) end with a null terminated character?  Or do I need to determine the length using `GetStringUTFLength` and null terminate it myself?

Comment: You could always check!

Comment: @Tdorno: I trust you mean *check the documentation* at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#wp17265 - which I suspect the original poster did, and it doesn't say one way or another.  Because just looking to see if there happens to be a NULL in memory at the end of where you think the string will end seems like a poor test of what `GetStringUTFChars` will *always* return...

Comment: The matter has been further, and definitely, clarified in Java 9 by Oracle. I added my own  [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65078336/213871) with references.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Yes, `GetStringUTFChars` returns a null-terminated string.  However, I don't think you should take my word for it, instead you should find an authoritative online source that answers this question.

Let's start with the actual [Java Native Interface Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/jniTOC.html) itself, where it says:

> Returns a pointer to an array of bytes representing the string in modified UTF-8 encoding.  This array is valid until it is released by `ReleaseStringUTFChars()`.

Oh, surprisingly it doesn't say whether it's null-terminated or not.  Boy, that seems like a huge oversight, and fortunately somebody was kind enough to log this bug on [Sun's Java bug database](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6681965) back in 2008.  The notes on the bug point you to [a similar but different documentation bug](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4616318) (which was closed without action), which suggests that the readers buy a book, "[The Java Native Interface: Programmer's Guide and Specification](http://amzn.to/1XctryV)" as there's a suggestion that this become the new specification for JNI.

But we're looking for an authoritative online source, and this is neither authoritative (it's not *yet* the specification) nor online.

Fortunately, the reviews for said book on a certain popular online book retailer suggest that the book is freely available online from Sun, and that would at least satisfy the online portion.  Sun's [JNI web page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/) has a link that looks tantalizingly close, but that link sadly doesn't go where it says it goes.

So I'm afraid I cannot point you to an authoritative online source for this, and you'll have to buy the book (it's actually a good book), where it will explain to you that:

> UTF-8 strings are always terminated with the `'\0'` character, whereas Unicode strings are not.  To find out how many bytes are needed to represent a `jstring` in the UTF-8 format, JNI programmers can either call the ANSI C function `strlen` on the result of `GetStringUTFChars`, or call the JNI function `GetStringUTFLength` on the `jstring` reference directly.

(Note that in the above sentence, "Unicode" means "UTF-16", or more accurately "the internal two-byte string representation used by Java, though finding proof of *that* is left as an exercise for the reader.)

Comment: If it is not specified then it is up for a Java implementation to do or not do since doing does not violate the spec. It is then up to consumers of the JNI API to rely on undocumented behavior or not, and also to use safe C functions or not. Besides, the common C functions that operate on UTF-8 strings are encoding-conversion functions. Many of those take the size of the string as a parameter, not relying on the null-termination concept at all.

Comment: @TomBlodget I see what you're saying, but realistically, any alternative Java runtime implementation is going to have to be compatible with what Sun's JNI implementation *does*, regardless of the crappy spec, the horror that is "modified UTF-8" and everything.  IBM certainly behaves identically (except when using EBCDIC, of course).  You're welcome to allocate another, identical string, *just in case* you come across some JVM that doesn't null-terminate, but that seems unnecessary since every other piece of JNI is *also* going to crash.

Comment: You can find the pdf by doing a search for "the java native interface pdf". It is also available on Google Books, which allows you preview a limited number of pages (good for verifying things such as this.)

Comment: **Wow**. +1 for the search effort... I actually got caught up in the reading: you are the Conan Doyle of the documentation mysteries ;-) (seriously, a very good job).

Answer (score 7):

All current answers to the question seem to be outdated (Edward Thomson's answer last update dates back to 2015), or referring to Android JNI documentation which can be authoritative only in the Android world. The matter has been clarified in recent (2017) official Oracle JNI documentation clean-up and [updates](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8079466), more specifically in this [issue](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6681965).

Now the [JNI](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/specs/jni/functions.html#string-operations) specification clearly states:

> **String Operations**
>
> This specification makes no assumptions on how a JVM
> represent Java strings internally. Strings returned from these
> operations:
>
> - GetStringChars()
> - GetStringUTFChars()
> - GetStringRegion()
> - GetStringUTFRegion()
> - GetStringCritical()
>
> are therefore not required to
> be NULL terminated. Programmers are expected to determine buffer
> capacity requirements via GetStringLength() or GetStringUTFLength().

In the general case this means one should never assume JNI returned strings are null terminated, not even UTF-8 strings. In a pragmatic world one can test a specific behavior in a list of supported JVM(s). In my experience, rereferring to JVMs I actually tested:

- Oracle JVMs do null terminate both UTF-16 (with `\u0000`) and UTF-8 strings (with `'\0'`);
- Android JVMs do terminate UTF-8 strings but not UTF-16 ones.

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni says:

The Java programming language uses UTF-16. For convenience, JNI provides methods that work with Modified UTF-8 as well. The modified encoding is useful for C code because it encodes \u0000 as 0xc0 0x80 instead of 0x00. The nice thing about this is that **you can count on having C-style zero-terminated** strings, suitable for use with standard libc string functions. The down side is that you cannot pass arbitrary UTF-8 data to JNI and expect it to work correctly.

If possible, it's usually faster to operate with UTF-16 strings. Android currently does not require a copy in GetStringChars, whereas GetStringUTFChars requires an allocation and a conversion to UTF-8. **Note that UTF-16 strings are not zero-terminated**, and \u0000 is allowed, so you need to hang on to the string length as well as the jchar pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, strings returned by GetStringUTFChars() are null-terminated. I use it in my application, so proved it experimentally, let's say. While Oracle's documentation sucks, alternative sources are more informative: [Java Native Interface (JNI) Tutorial](https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/JavaNativeInterface.html)

Comment: That is a fine tutorial except it assumes `GetStringUTFChars` returns an array suitable for the `char` version of `print`. The array contains UTF-8 code units not one-byte characters. To get to a one-byte per character encoding, you need a conversion. Or, you could compile the C code for Unicode and use `wchar_t` functions directly.

Comment: "It works for me" is not proof that it works *all of the time* and will continue to work in all future Java implementations, it's only proof that it happens to work *some of the time*.

Comment: @AdamRosenfield, what's your point? Still in doubt - call Oracle or look inside JVM source code. There might be no JVM at all in future, so what?

Comment: @Archie: My point is that there is not just one JVM, there are alternative JVM implementations.  Just because a particular JVM does things one way does not mean that other JVMs have to that the same way or that that JVM won't change how it behaves in the future, as long as the Java Language Spec doesn't specify how a particular thing must function.